# RESTful POST Response

Tags: rest, httprequest, httpresponse

I have an extremely simple RESTful service that receives some form data via POST, it's purpose of which is to simply retain the body of text (with a unique id) in cloud storage (Amazon S3, Azure Blob Storage, etc.) as a file...

So, question is.. if everything is good, and i return a 200 response to the caller, what should i return to the caller in terms of a body?

Anything?
Nothing?

If this were creating a database record.. perhaps the id of that new record might be useful.. but in this instance, i'm thinking simply the HttpRepsone code is sufficient?

Anyone agree, disagree, or have a supporting link with discussion?

I should add that the requests to this service are pretty much.. hand off, and go.. they don't actually *need* the unique id that i am proposing to send back.. this is more for "completeness".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Short answer

Once you are *creating a resource on the server*, you should return the [`201`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2) status code along with a [`Location`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) header, allowing the client to locate the newly created resource.

The response payload is optional and it typically describes and links to the resource created.

### A bit longer answer

See the following quote from the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [**4.3.3.  POST**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)
>
> [...] If one or more resources has been created on the origin server as a result of successfully processing a `POST` request, the origin server SHOULD send a `201` (Created) response containing a `Location` header field that provides an identifier for the primary resource created and a representation that describes the status of the request while referring to the new resource(s). [...]

Also from the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [**6.3.2.  201 Created**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2)
>
> The `201` (Created) status code indicates that the request has been fulfilled and has resulted in one or more new resources being created.  The primary resource created by the request is identified by either a `Location` header field in the response or, if no `Location` field is received, by the effective request URI.
>
> The `201` response payload typically describes and links to the resource(s) created. [...]

> [**7.1.2.  Location**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2)
>
> The `Location` header field is used in some responses to refer to a specific resource in relation to the response.  The type of relationship is defined by the combination of request method and status code semantics.
>
> ```
> Location = URI-reference
> ```
>
> The field value consists of a single URI-reference. [...] For `201` (Created) responses, the `Location` value refers to the primary resource created by the request. [...]

Comment: v. informative answer. i'll return a 201 but a location of the created resource is slightly redundant as the service poster will never have permission to access that data.. if it is good practice to return the location, i will at least return the uniqueid, does it make sense for this to be in the location header still?

Comment: @m1nkeh The RCF 7231 says that the `Location` value consists of a single URI. But why would a client be able to create a resource on the server and won't be a able to retrieve a representation of such resource later?

Comment: oh, it's a form submission on a website.. the submitted data is only of interest to other systems.. the website only cares that the submission and creation of asset was successful.. no need to ever get it back.

Answer (score 1):

> I should add that the requests to this service are pretty much.. hand off, and go.. they don't actually need the unique id

Its absolutely fine to return nothing in response to a post request. You are saying it's not even required by the caller. But the status code 201 will make more sense.

Comment: cool.. i'll switch my response from a 200 to a 201 in that case ;)